# how to find out the size of column in a matrix with help of fscanf?

Tags: c

I am reading matrix through file with the help of `fscanf()`. 
With the `fscanf()` I am able to extract the matrix from the file.
But I am not able to find out the column size of matrix.

input file is :
12 3 -4
                                                                                                                                                                                                                6 5 7

```
int main()
{
    char arr[10],len;
    int count=0;

    FILE *input= fopen("input.txt", "r"); 

    while(fscanf(input,"%s",arr) != EOF)
    {   
        //fill into the output matrix. 
    }   
}
```

But how to find out the size of column  with  help of `fscanf`?

Comment: What does the file look like ?

Comment: input file is :                                                             12 3 -4                                                                                                                                    6 5 7

Comment: You have a `count` variable in your code. I suspect it is there to help you track the number of elements in the array. You just need to increment it inside the loop everytime you read a new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first time, even if function getColumn try read.

```
int getColumn(FILE* fp){
    char buff[BUFSIZ]={0};
    int count=0;
    char *p;
    if(NULL==fgets(buff, BUFSIZ, fp))
        return -1;
    rewind(fp);
    for(p=buff;NULL!=strtok(p, " \t\n");p=NULL)
        ++count;
    return count;
}

...
FILE *input= fopen("input.txt", "r");
int column = getColumn(input);//3
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) should do. You can get the length of the line from strlen which you are looking for.
If each column elements are separated by space or any delimiter all you have to do is split the line with the delimiter and get individual element. Please reply in case of any doubts.